# How to use short names for types in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ cannot accept short names for object types I need. `Incompatible types` error is generated. How fix it?

[image]

Comment: This isn't IntelliJ, this is Java.  Are you sure you have the correct `import` at the top of your code?  Do you have multiple types called `DSLR`?

Comment: Seems like `dslrDAO` has incorrect imports of `DSLR` within itself. Now it's working

Answer (score 2):

### It's IntelliJ IDEA!

You need mark your `java` folder as `Sources Root`.

[image]

Then `java` dir should be look like on image:

[image]

---

For more details see this guides:

- [Configuring Folders Within a Content Root](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html)
- [Configuring Module Roots](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-roots.html)